# Visual Studio 2019: how to disable specific CodeAnalysis messages in .editorconfig?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, roslyn-code-analysis, editorconfig

Is it possible to suppress CodeAnalysis messages in VS 2019 `.editorconfig` ? These two options don't work:

```
[*.cs]
#Trying alternatives to
#[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Design", "CA1051:Do not declare visible instance fields", Justification = "<Pending>")]
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1051.severity = silent 
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.CA1051.severity = silent
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, rule severity is configurable in an EditorConfig file in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 or newer ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#set-rule-severity-in-an-editorconfig-file)).

To suppress a rule violation, you should set the severity to `none`:

```
dotnet_diagnostic.CA1051.severity = none
```

This worked for me after I edited the config file and restarted Visual Studio.

Comment: Just for anyone landing on this answer and creating an .editorconfig file consistently SOLELY of this line, that won't work - you need the "[*.cs]" line present in the original question content. But otherwise, fantastic - thanks!

Comment: Also note that, `none` and `silent` are different, and in some (if not most?) cases `silent` should be preferred instead of `none`, and also note that some places refer to `suppress` and `hidden` as options, but they're actually not: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/35690

Comment: Is there a way to completely switch off Roslyn compilation without having to install Visual Studio?  Can I create the .editorconfig file using a text editor in the directory with  C-Sharp modules.  The youtube video at https://youtu.be/xZTZJVnFAgw demonstrates the problem I am encountering with IIS.

Comment: @chribonn yes, you can just make the file manually

Comment: @user15716642 At the end of the day the only way I could resolve this was to install Visual Studio 2022 and compile each .cs specifically eliminating the Roslyn modules.  It would have been great had I been able to tell IIS that "this website" should work as it did pre-.NET Core.