# Disable Roslyn code analysers on a specific project

Tags: .net, msbuild, roslyn, xunit.net, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to add custom assertions to XUnit's `Assert`, so:

- I created a "helper" project that references the nuget package [`xunit.assert.source`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.assert.source/)
- I add my custom assertions in that project
- I referenced that helper project from my test project.

That works.

However because that is imported as source, I get hundreds of code analyzer warnings on every build in the cli, and my vscode goes crazy by performing analysis as well.

I tried - unsuccessfully - to disable it for that project by doing this in the csproj:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>false</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

How can I disable analysis for that specific project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can disable code analysers in `.editorconfig`: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58437279/67392).
2. An `editorconfig` in a child folder (setting `root = false`) will override/extend an `.editorconfig` in an ancestor folder.

So add a project specific `editorconfig` and use that to disable all the analysers you want to.

Comment: I also set all these to false: `<EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>`, `<RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>`, `<RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>`, `<RunAnalyzers>`. Then I added `<NoWarn>` for those warnings that still wouldn't shut up.